# haProxy : Stop / Resume WebSocket Forwarding

Tags: haproxy

I am using haProxy (Debian) to distribute websocket connections through 4 servers.

```
                      +-----> webSocket 1
                      |
                      +-----> webSocket 2
public websocket ip --+
                      +-----> webSocket 3
                      |
                      +-----> webSocket 4
```

Without interrupting public websocket ip nor webSocket server, is it possible to instruct haProxy to stop forwarding connections to a specific server ? If so, how to resume then ?

```
                      +-----> webSocket 1
                      |
                      +-----> webSocket 2
public websocket ip --+
                      +--x--> webSocket 3
                      |
                      +-----> webSocket 4
```

Or .. since I am limiting connections to 50 per webSocket, is it possible to ask haProxy to start webSocket instances (it's a NODE JS script) when required ? And when not required, is it going to stop the service to free up memory ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make it stop sending new connections to one of the backend servers by using the admin socket and sending the enable/disable server commands to the socket. Also you could use to "set server state drain" command to the same socket to allow the current websocket sessions to finish and only then completely disable that backend.

Regarding the second thing, haproxy does not know how to do that. You can create an utility to read the current state of the system in haproxy and do this job.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/249316/how-can-i-remove-balanced-node-from-haproxy-via-command-line